# Ждем Вас за покупками

Tags: управление

Правильно ли употребление "ждем Вас за покупками" ?
Какое управление ждать + за (ждать за углом - понятно, а в значении, что придете за покупками)?

Answer (score 2):

Скорей всего, "Ждём вас за покупками!" - усечённая в результате частого употребления фраза "Ждём вас.Приходите за покупками!" Она имеет разговорный характер, простая, незамысловатая, легко вошла в нашу речь. Думаю, что в разговорном стиле она вполне допустима. 
У предлога ЗА очень много значений. Одно из них такое:
***23. кем-чем. 

Указывает на лицо, предмет и т.п., которые нужно достать, добыть, привести и т.п. Послать за врачом. Заехать за вещами. Идти за водой.***  [Посмотрите здесь, интересно](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%E7%E0&all=x)

Answer (score 1):

Действительно режет слух. Но если это рекламный слоган, то там такие вещи часто делают намерено. Именно для того, чтобы задержать на какое-то время внимание читающего.

> Какое управление ждать + за (ждать за углом - понятно, а в значении, что придете за покупками)?

Вопроса не понял. Управление - творительным падежом, это, полагаю, Вы и без меня знаете. А то, что в скобках: "ждать за углом - понятно" - да; "а в значении, что придете за покупками" - не понял совсем.

Если вы спрашиваете о том, допустимо ли использование "ждать за чем" в значении "с какой целью" , подобно "приходите за покупками", то я уже ответил, что нет, во всяком случае - в обычном употреблении.

Как сделать фразу нормативной, не убирая этого "ждать за" - не знаю, в таком виде, как ни переделывай, фраза будет означать, что "Вас" ждут позади кучи из сваленных "покупок". Надо менять кардинально, если коненчо тут не используется рекламный ход, о котором я сказал.

Кстати, очень большой вопрос, нужно ли тут "Вас" с заглавной. Авторы расходятся в рекомендациях, но я полагаю, что здесь идет обращение ко ***всем*** покупателям - т.е. к каждому, а не к одному конкретному, поэтому естественно "вы" со строчной. Но это мое мнение.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, это рекламный слоган. Проще "Приходите к нам за покупками" или "Ждем вас (в нашем магазине)"